# How to Lazy Load RabbitMQ queue using @Lazy in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, lazy-loading, spring-rabbit

Actually in my RabbitMQ config I have declared 10 consumers for each queue. So all consumer threads are created before my Spring Boot application is fully up so it is taking time on application startup.

I want to lazy load all my Rabbitmq queue when my project is up. I tried using `@Lazy` on the configuration class but it does not seem working.

Is there any way to declare lazy load queue ?

Comment: Maybe it can help you [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/issues/923)

Answer (score 2):

Set `autoStartup="false"` on the `@RabbitListener` (or listener container).

Then start the listeners manually.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#container-management

for `@RabbitListener` or just `start()` the containers if they are beans.

Comment: I am configuring my listener in setMessageListener in SimpleMessageListenerContainer(not using @Rabbitlister annotation) how to start listener in this case if i have set auto startup property to false because in this case they are not registered in RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry

Comment: You can use normal bean injection (`@Autowired` etc).

Comment: I have used getBean method of ApplicationContext to inject ListenerClass bean but the listenerClass does not start listening (the Queue has already some data in it).            I have also try to use @Inject to inject listenerclass but it also not working

Comment: You need to start the `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` bean not the listener class.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is set "autoStartup=false" to @RabbitListener:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "${yourqueue}",autoStartup = "false")
```

And then find all registered rabbit listeners and start it:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    ConfigurableApplicationContext run = SpringApplication.run(SimPurchaseApplication.class, args);

    RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry rabbitListeners = run.getBean(RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry.class);
    for (MessageListenerContainer listenerContainer : rabbitListeners.getListenerContainers()){
        listenerContainer.start();
    }
}
```